# Angular, the link has changed but the page is not loading

Tags: angular, routes

I want to go to the next word when I click **Skip**, but when I click **Skip** the link changed but the next word doesn't appear in place of the old word, and there are no error messages in the console. This is the code for the **Skip** button:

```
next() {
  this.lessonService.getNextLessonElement(this.elementId).subscribe({
    next: response => {
      console.log('go to level')
      console.log('/level/'+this.lessonId+'/'+response.id)
      this.router.navigate(['/level/'+this.lessonId+'/'+response.id]);

      // this.router.navigate(['level']);
    }
    , error: (err: AppError) => {
      if (err instanceof NotFoundError) {
        console.log(err)
      }
    }
  })
}
```

```
<div class="flex-column flex-center">
      <div class="block">
        <h2 class="title">Try to repeat this word:</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="flex-row">
        <h3 class="sentence">{{ element.element }}</h3>
        <i
          class="fa fa-volume-off fa-3x block micro"
          (click)="textToSpeech(element.element || 'undefined')"
        ></i>
      </div>
      <div *ngIf="!recording" (click)="startRecording()" class="mic">
        <i class="fa fa-microphone fa-5x micro" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        Start Recording
      </div>
      <div *ngIf="recording" (click)="stopRecording()" class="mic">
        <i
          class="fa fa-microphone fa-5x"
          aria-hidden="true"
          style="color: red"
        ></i>
        <div style="color: red">Stop Recording</div>
      </div>
      <audio controls="" *ngIf="url">
        <source [src]="sanitize(url)" type="audio/wav" />
      </audio>
    </div>

<button mat-flat-button color="warn" (click)="next()">Skip</button>
```

```
const routes: Routes = [
  path: 'level', component: LevelComponent },
  path: 'level/:lessonid/:elementid', component: LevelComponent },
];
```

Comment: You'll want to provide the community with more info for this.  Can you show your routes you've declared?  Can you show the component that shows the words?

Comment: @JakeSmith I changed my post, is these informations enough?

Comment: You need to subscribe to you queryparams. due to the fact that you navigate to the same component. It does not detroy and recreate. Then you can update the view based on the lessonid and elementid